# conda requirements vs constraints

Tags: python, conda

In the following is part of the package meta data for clang `~/conda/pkgs/clang-13.0.0-ha770c72_0/info/repodata_record.json`, which has two sections "constrains" and "depends"

```json
{
  "arch": "x86_64",
  "build": "ha770c72_0",
  "build_number": 0,
  "channel": "https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64",
  "constrains": [
    "libclang 13.0.0.*",
    "clang-tools 13.0.0.*",
    "llvm 13.0.0.*",
    "llvm-tools 13.0.0.*",
    "llvmdev 13.0.0.*"
  ],
  "depends": [
    "clang-13 13.0.0 default_hc23dcda_0",
    "gcc_impl_linux-64"
  ],
  ...
}
```

What are the items listed in "constrains" and "depends"?

I suspect that "depends" means that if we need to install `clang` version 13.0.0 we need also install `clang-13` version 13.0.0 and `gcc_impl_linux-64`. Is this correct?

Then how about the constrains? Does this clang package also rely on those packages such as `llvm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four types of requirements that can be defined in a Conda recipe: `build`, `host`, `run`, and `run_constrained`. The last two get translated to `depends` and `constrains` in the final metadata JSON, respectively.

The `run` requirements identify packages that must be co-installed; the `run_constrained` defines version constraints *if* the listed packages are co-installed.

For details, see [the documentation on the **Requirements section**](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#requirements-section) for a Conda package recipe's `meta.yaml` file.

Also, see [the Conda Forge recipe](https://github.com/conda-forge/clangdev-feedstock/blob/f94b4cb272bf2163513b577cc343fc2867bbf229/recipe/meta.yaml#L212) for the `clang-{{major_version}}` package.